# Creating text box programmatically and accessing it in another function

Tags: c#, dynamic

```
private void AddModuleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox[] ModuleNameTF = new TextBox[NoOfModules];
}

private void SummaryViewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

I have 2 click events. How would I access the textbox that I created from AddModule to the Summaryview?

Comment: If you know the number of textboxes in advance you can build them, then hide/show when you click the button.

Comment: Your AddModule button isn't creating any textboxes. Also, please improve your formatting.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I access the textbox that I created from AddModule to the Summaryview?

Up to now you have not created a single `TextBox`. You created only a local array that can hold objects of type `TextBox`. To answer the first part of your question: you need to move the declaration of the array outside of the scope of the `AddModuleButton_Click` method. The initialization can stay inside:

```
TextBox[] ModuleNameTF;

private void AddModuleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ModuleNameTF = new TextBox[NoOfModules];
}
```

Now `ModuleNameTF` becomes accessible throughout the entire class. You just need to use the `[ ]` operator to index the array:

```
private void SummaryViewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ModuleNameTF[0].Text = "From SummaryView method";
}
```

Don't forget to fill your array with actual `TextBox`es. Otherwise the access in `SummaryViewButton_Click` will fail.